# Get rows within current month

Tags: sql, postgresql

Get the rows from a table filtered by current month in psql.

Example table -

```
+--------------+--------------------+--------------------------+
|    id        |     name           |    registeration_date    |
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
|    1         |     abc            | 2018|12|31 18:30:00|00   |
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
|    2         |     pqr            | 2018|11|31 18:30:00|00   |
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
|    3         |     lmn            | 2020|07|10 18:30:00|00   |
+--------------+--------------------+--------------------------+
```

After query result, assuming current month is `July, 2020`:

```
+--------------+--------------------+--------------------------+
|    id        |     name           |    registeration_date    |
+--------------+--------------------+--------------------------+
|    3         |     lmn            | 2020|07|10 18:30:00|00   |
+--------------+--------------------+--------------------------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual approach is to use a range query to allow for an index usage on `registration_date`

```
select *
from the_table
where registration_date >= date_trunc('month', current_date) 
  and registration_date < date_trunc('month', current_date)  + interval '1 month';
```

Comment: What will be the difference if we use the extract? I couldn't follow on the index usage thing.

Comment: If there is an index on `registration_date` this query can make use of it to improve performance. The alternative with `extract()` can not, and will have to scan the entire table which is typically slower.

Answer (score 0):

In this, I use `Extract` function. For more details on `extract`check [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT).

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE extract(month from registeration_date) = extract(month from current_date)
AND extract(year from registeration_date) = extract(year from current_date)
```